# Read bluetooth connections in React Native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

I just need to know if there is a paired device and it's name, have searched around for a while but only found some complicated solutions, is there something like [@react-native-community/netinfo](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo) but for bluetooth?